# Error while instantiating an object without inheritance

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

So far I was using classes inheriting from other classes, now I had the need to creating a class inheriting from anything. I called it from my client class and I'm getting error that doesn't make sense to me. what am I doing wrong?

#### MathHelp .h

```
public:
    float addPerc(float whole, float perc);
    float subPerc(float whole, float perc);
```

#### MathHelp .cpp

```
float addPerc(float whole, float perc)
{
    return 0;
}

float subPerc(float whole, float perc)
{
    return 0;
}
```

calling from client

```
MathHelp* mathHelp = new MathHelp();
float mathResult = mathHelp->addPerc(100,5);
```

#### Error:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: float __thiscall MathHelp::addPerc(float,float)" (?addPerc@MathHelp@@QAEMMM@Z)
referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall EnergyManager::draw(class cocos2d::Renderer *,class cocos2d::Mat4 const &,unsigned int)" (?draw@EnergyManager@@UAEXPAVRenderer@cocos2d@@ABVMat4@3@I@Z)
```

Comment: You feel like sharing the error message?

Comment: oh, how could I forget. Doing it now.

Comment: Please don't post unreadable image, post the text itself!

Comment: why so many down votes? I don't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method declarations need to also have the name of the class when you're declaring them outside of the class definition.

```
float MathHelp::addPerc(float whole, float perc)
{
    return 0;
}

float MathHelp::subPerc(float whole, float perc)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: of course, I was testing static methods and didn't move back the class name with ::, thanks man

Answer (score 0):

With the code that has been provided, if they are taken as they directly appear in the files, you are missing the scope for the methods of the class MathHelp, you'd instead want to try something like this:

```
float MathHelp::addPerc(float whole, float perc)
{
    return 0;
}

float MathHelp::subPerc(float whole, float perc)
{
    return 0;
}
```